# List which automatically removes the oldest item when I add a new one

Tags: c#, list, queue

I need a class in C# to store **not more than last N** items with following method:

```
Add(T item) {
    if (mylist.Count >= N)
        remove the first(oldest) item;
    add a new item to the tail;
}
```

and with property which gets the item at the specified index.
So probably the right way is based my class on one of the classes: List, Queue, ConcurrentQueue, Dequeue (may be something different?). Of course, a class should provide an equal access time to a head and a tail.
The question is, what class the most acceptable for my purpose?

Comment: _equal access time to a head and a tail._ sounds like a subclass from the regular List<T>

Comment: Does `List<T>` provide equal access time to its head and its tail?

Comment: Well it depends on the number of elemtents you want to store. [Here](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/06/16/c.net-fundamentals-choosing-the-right-collection-class.aspx) is a comparison. For __smaller  n__ or for doing lots of __lookups__ List<T> would be fine. For large n others may be better..

Comment: Yeah, it is really interesting reference, but I still dont see what I need. And `List` doesn't store a link to its tail, so efficiency is o(n).

Answer (score 3):

Use the LinkedList(t) to do this with. That gives you a First, Last, and Count. This way once the count got to a certain point, the last can be removed.

```
myList = new LinkedList();

Add(T item){
    if (myList.Count >= N)
        myList.RemoveLast();
    myList.AddFirst(item);
}
```

In this case, the last item is the oldest, and the first item is the newest.

Comment: Um... I dont wanna be boring, but 'LinkedList' is too much for my purpose, I actually dont need a link to previous node in each node.

Answer (score 0):

So I report about my researching.
Class `List<T>` in C# is actually a vector, not a list in the sense defined in computer science. `LinkedList<T>` is really a list, but doubly linked.
I wrote very simple class to solve my task.

```
/// <summary>
/// Fixed-size buffer. When the buffer is full adding a new item removes the first item,
/// so buffer stores the last N (where N is a size) adding items.
/// Reading is provided by indexing, rewriting isn't allowed.
/// Buffer could be changed by using method Add only.
/// </summary>
public class RingBuffer<T> {
    int size;
    T[] ringbuffer;
    int i0 = 0, count = 0;

    int getIndex(int i) {
        int k=i0+i;
        return k < count ? k : k-size;
    }
    public RingBuffer(int size) {
        this.size = size;
        ringbuffer = new T[size];
    }
    public int Count {
        get { return count; }
    }
    public bool isFull {
        get { return count == size; }
    }
    public T this[int i] {
        get { return ringbuffer[getIndex(i)]; }
    }
    public void Add(T item) {
        if (isFull)
            // rewrite the first item
            ringbuffer[i0++] = item;
        else
            ringbuffer[count++] = item;
    }
}
```